# is there a way to apply dry and solid principal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, dry, solid-principles

I am working on this code to make it shorter so that it could be easier to study or read and I have but advanced to apply the dry and solid principle so could you help me with how to refactor this ruby on rails code which contains some if statements  to do this.so that it becomes more easy to read and shorter using those principles.

```
if brand.rating = high
  if price_reference < 15
    price_suggestion = (price_reference - product_database.shipping_cost * 0.75) * 1.1
    price_original = price_suggestion
  elsif price_reference < 25
    price_suggestion = (price_reference - product_database.shipping_cost * 0.775) * 1.1
    price_original = price_suggestion
  elsif price_reference < 50
    price_suggestion = (price_reference - product_database.shipping_cost * 0.8) * 1.1
    price_original = price_suggestion
  elsif price_reference < 75
    price_suggestion = (price_reference - product_database.shipping_cost * 0.825) * 1.1
    price_original = price_suggestion
  elsif price_reference < 100
    price_suggestion = (price_reference - product_database.shipping_cost * 0.85) * 1.1
    price_original = price_suggestion
  elsif price_reference < 200
    price_suggestion = (price_reference - product_database.shipping_cost * 0.875) * 1.1
    price_original = price_suggestion
  elsif price_reference < 400
    price_suggestion = (price_reference - product_database.shipping_cost * 0.9) * 1.1
    price_original = price_suggestion
  elsif price_reference < 600
    price_suggestion = (price_reference - product_database.shipping_cost * 0.925) * 1.1
    price_original = price_suggestion
  else
    price_suggestion = (price_reference - product_database.shipping_cost * 0.95) * 1.1
    price_original = price_suggestion
elsif brand.rating = low
  if price_reference < 15
    price_suggestion = (price_reference - product_database.shipping_cost * 0.75) * 0.9
    price_original = price_suggestion
  elsif price_reference < 25
    price_suggestion = (price_reference - product_database.shipping_cost * 0.775) * 0.9
    price_original = price_suggestion
  elsif price_reference < 50
    price_suggestion = (price_reference - product_database.shipping_cost * 0.8) * 0.9
    price_original = price_suggestion
  elsif price_reference < 75
    price_suggestion = (price_reference - product_database.shipping_cost * 0.825) * 0.9
    price_original = price_suggestion
  elsif price_reference < 100
    price_suggestion = (price_reference - product_database.shipping_cost * 0.85) * 0.9
    price_original = price_suggestion
  elsif price_reference < 200
    price_suggestion = (price_reference - product_database.shipping_cost * 0.875) * 0.9
    price_original = price_suggestion
  elsif price_reference < 400
    price_suggestion = (price_reference - product_database.shipping_cost * 0.9) * 0.9
    price_original = price_suggestion
  elsif price_reference < 600
    price_suggestion = (price_reference - product_database.shipping_cost * 0.925) * 0.9
    price_original = price_suggestion
  else
    price_suggestion = (price_reference - product_database.shipping_cost * 0.95) * 0.9
    price_original = price_suggestion
else
  if price_reference < 15
    price_suggestion = (price_reference - product_database.shipping_cost * 0.75) * 1
    price_original = price_suggestion
  elsif price_reference < 25
    price_suggestion = (price_reference - product_database.shipping_cost * 0.775) * 1
    price_original = price_suggestion
  elsif price_reference < 50
    price_suggestion = (price_reference - product_database.shipping_cost * 0.8) * 1
    price_original = price_suggestion
  elsif price_reference < 75
    price_suggestion = (price_reference - product_database.shipping_cost * 0.825) * 1
    price_original = price_suggestion
  elsif price_reference < 100
    price_suggestion = (price_reference - product_database.shipping_cost * 0.85) * 1
    price_original = price_suggestion
  elsif price_reference < 200
    price_suggestion = (price_reference - product_database.shipping_cost * 0.875) * 1
    price_original = price_suggestion
  elsif price_reference < 400
    price_suggestion = (price_reference - product_database.shipping_cost * 0.9) * 1
    price_original = price_suggestion
  elsif price_reference < 600
    price_suggestion = (price_reference - product_database.shipping_cost * 0.925) * 1
    price_original = price_suggestion
  else
    price_suggestion = (price_reference - product_database.shipping_cost * 0.95) * 1
    price_original = price_suggestion
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like:

```
def suggest_price(price_reference, shipping_cost)
  [
     [15, 0.75],
     [25, 0.775],
     [50, 0.8],
     ... etc ...
  ].each do |price_point, shipping_modifier|
    if price_reference < price_point
      return price_reference - shipping_cost * shipping_modifier
    end
  end
  return price_reference - shipping_cost * 0.95
end

def price_modifier(brand)
  if brand.rating == high
    1.1 
  elsif brand.rating == low
    0.9
  else
    1
  end
end

price_original = price_modifier(brand) * suggest_price(price_reference, product_database.shipping_cost)
```

I'm not suggesting that's perfect code but it's a way you could approach it. You'd probably want the price points and modifiers in a constant.

Answer (score 1):

You could apply some OOP. In the `Brand` class you could use some `.case` statements to make it more readable...

```
def prices
  case self.rating
    when 'high"
      case  
        when price_reference < 15
          (price_reference - product_database.shipping_cost * 0.75) * 1.1
        when price_reference < 25
          (price_reference - product_database.shipping_cost * 0.775) * 1.1
        when price_reference < 50
          (price_reference - product_database.shipping_cost * 0.8) * 1.1 
          etc...

    when 'low'
      case 
          etc...
    else
          etc...
  end
end
```

A nested `case` statement is a bit easier to read. Also you are doing a lot of unneeded variable reassignment. Remember that Ruby always returns the last statement it evaluates. So when you call the method on a member of the Brand class you can use it like this:

```
brand = Brand.new(rating: 'high', price_reference: '25')
#let's assume product_database.shipping_cost = 5
brand.prices
 #returns the value 23.2375 which came from (25 - 5 * 0.775) * 1.1
```

There are many ways to do this. You could abstract out a lot more of your code by creating some hash dictionaries to contain the values of each formula and then do variable substitution to call them. Try to thing in terms of objects and methods. Everything in Ruby is an object of some sort and you can create methods to call on those objects that call other methods and use other objects.

Comment: `price_reference` can be any value between `0...25`, `25...50` etc. not exactly that value

Comment: Well now you have simply created a `SyntaxError` when you said *"Will correct with [R]anges"* I thought okay great but then you didn't and everything broke :O